# Add K2 workflow designer to visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, k2

How can install K2 workfolw designer extention  to visual studio 2010 ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install it from the K2 Blackpearl installer. On the "Select Components" screen you'll see checkboxes for "K2 for Visual Studio 2010" option under "Client Components"